# Delphi - ControlListButton.OnClick - How to determine AIndex from ControlList

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Delphi - ControlListButton.OnClick - How to determine AIndex from ControlList

Hello I am developing a calendar form and I am trying to find the Index of a ControlListButton that is within a ControlList. In the BeforeDrawItem the Label.Caption is set to  a description from a ClientDataSet

ControlList.BeforeDrawItem has a row that uses AIndex

```
procedure TFormCalendarViewMonthly.ControlListDayBeforeDrawItem(
  AIndex: Integer; ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; AState: 
TOwnerDrawState);
  begin
    clientDataSet.RecNo:=AIndex;
   etc..
end;
```

The ControlListButtonClick only shows with Sender. How do I get the AIndex of the click that was created during the BeforeDraw?

ie.

```
procedure TFormCalendarViewMonthly.ControlListButtonClick(Sender: 
TObject);
  begin
   //AIndex is not part of the procedure
end;
```

Should I use the ClientDataSet.RecNo as the Index for the Row that was clicked in the ControlList? Or is there a way in the ButtonClick to see the row that was selected?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently selected row of a `TControlList` can be read from its `ItemIndex` property.